# Make includes() exact with numbers JS

Tags: javascript

How do I make it show me accuracy in includes() or maybe another way...
For example I do.

```
array.filter(item => {
if(item?.about?.toLowerCase()?.includes(
  ("4")) && item?.about?.toLowerCase()?.includes(
    ("years") 
  )
```

But in the text itself it is written, for example, "We have existed for 40 years". 
It recognizes for me the number 4 within the 40 and then it filters it.
what can we do ?

Comment: what do you want to do ?!

Comment: I don't understand the desired result, do you want to only match exactly "4 years" but not 40? Why can't you look for `"4 years"` rather than two separate strings? Are there other acceptable quantities or inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex for this to include multiple test as a single pattern:

```
/(^4|[^\d]+4)[^\d]+years.*/i
```

**Explanation:**

1. (^4|[^\d]+4): Either string start with 4 or has a non-numeric character before it.
2. [^\d]+: Followed by at least 1 non-numeric character.
3. years: Followed by exact word *years*
4. .*: Means you can have any characters after it or be at the end.
5. /i: Means it will check case insensitively. So you do not have to do `.toLowerCase()`

   ```js
   const data = [
     "We have existed for 40 years",
     "We have existed for 4 years",
     "We have existed for 44 years",
     "4 years at start",
     "4 is a random number in years"
   ]

   const output = data.filter((str) => {
     const regex = /(^4|[^\d]+4)[^\d]+years.*/i;
     return regex.test(str)
   });

   console.log(output)
   ```

Comment: **Note:** I'm no expert in regex but this will do for given usecase. If you have better regex for this, please either comment and I'll tag you in update or just update yourself tagging yourself. Thanks!